# Simplest way to use CSS to fade in an overlay block

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/T5pX2/

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.overlay {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
}

<div class="block">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. How and when should the overlay happen?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking like this.

```
.block {
position: relative;
margin: 25px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.overlay
{
  opacity: 0;
}
.block:hover .overlay {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: yellow;    
opacity: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5pX2/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can that be animated? I know how to use the hover but want it to fade in, as opposed to just appear.

Comment: Tech I don't believe this is a fade in because there is no timing.

Answer (score 8):

What you have at the moment is not an overlay it's just one div inside another.

To make it an overlay you need to use `position:absolute` as follows:

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/T5pX2/7/)

**CSS**

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:1em;
}
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.block:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You did not specify, so I can only assume you want to use CSS animations to fade in the opacity:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.overlay {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.overlay').addClass('fade-in');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T5pX2/4/)

---

After requesting to work without javascript here is a keyframes solution that starts on page load:

```
.overlay.fade-in {
 -webkit-animation: fade-yellow 5s infinite;
 -moz-animation: fade-yellow 5s infinite;
 -o-animation: fade-yellow 5s infinite;
 animation: fade-yellow 5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-yellow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

[No JS Keyframe DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T5pX2/9/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say animate but yes, that's exactly what I was intending. Using CSS though, not javascript.

Comment: Sure, you'll need to use keyframes then. I will edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: @Andy I added a no JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .block {
                position: relative;
                width: 300px;
                height: 100px;
                background: blue;
            }

            .overlay {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background: red;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: 1s;
                -moz-transition: 1s;
                -webkit-transition: 1s;
                -ms-transition: 1s;
                -o-transition: 1s;
            }

            .overlay:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: auto;">
        <div class="block">
            Block
            <div class="overlay">
                Overlay
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```